# ASP.net Prevent white page flashing when user clicks in a local link

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-ajax, master-pages

For example in this page http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html when you click in each link in the navbar the browser loads the desired page without flashing a blank page first (Ajax like). In our website when clicking in the navbar it flashes instead

We are using MasterPages, Twitter BootStrap, ASP.net Framework 4

Testing our site with different browsers it does it in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE9, the bootstrap website doesnt have this problem in any of them...